# How to optimize EF/LINQ query to get a single rather than nested SELECT statement

Tags: linq

The following LINQ executes query which takes 90 milliseconds to execute:

```
.Where(Function(i) (i.RequestedByUserId = MySession.ApplicationUserId) 
    And (i.RequestKey1 = searchJson) 
    And (i.RequestMethod = "ProjectPlanService.GetProjectPlanMaintenanceData"))
      .Select(Function(i) i.ResultJson).FirstOrDefault
```

The SQL generated is as below :

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[ResultJson] AS [ResultJson]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[ResultJson] AS [ResultJson]
    FROM [dbo].[ApplicationCache] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[RequestedByUserId] = 2) AND ([Extent1].[RequestKey1] = '{"SortProperty":"","SortOrder":0,"PageNumber":1,"RecordsPerPage":15,"CriteriaCount":"1","CriteriaString":"~=~Id"}') AND ('ProjectPlanService.GetProjectPlanMaintenanceData' = [Extent1].[RequestMethod])
)  AS [Limit1]
```

1. How Can I optimize the above LINQ expression to reduce the time taken to execute?
2. Is there a way to get a single Select statement like below:

```
SELECT 
[ResultJson] 
    FROM [dbo].[ApplicationCache] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[RequestedByUserId] = 2) AND ([Extent1].[RequestKey1] = '{"SortProperty":"","SortOrder":0,"PageNumber":1,"RecordsPerPage":15,"CriteriaCount":"1","CriteriaString":"~=~Id"}') AND ('ProjectPlanService.GetProjectPlanMaintenanceData' = [Extent1].[RequestMethod])
```

Comment: Why did you kill the formatting?

Comment: And honestly you must have bigger fish to fry than trying to micro-optimize a query that takes 90ms.

Comment: I guess you added the appropriate index for this already? Very simple query to optimize. You should see single-digit ms numbers (like 0-2ms + network latency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: There's no need to optimise, it's just fine as it is - The extra "wrapping" won't change anything.

2: It's doing a top 1 because you asked for FirstOrDefault(), if you want a full list of results don't do that.

Comment: Thanks ! I get the point , I need only one row and guess this is optimized.